# SQL select complete row with largest value in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table:

| account | item | quantity | pending | sequence | update_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20.0 | 0.0 | 1 | (some time) |
| 2 | 1 | 10.0 | 0.0 | 2 | (some time) |
| 3 | 1 | 100.0 | 0.0 | 3 | (some time) |
| 1 | 1 | 20.0 | 5.0 | 4 | (some time) |
| 2 | 1 | 10.0 | 10.5 | 4 | (some time) |
| 3 | 1 | 100.0 | 100.0 | 6 | (some time) |
| 1 | 1 | 25.0 | 0.0 | 7 | (some time) |
| 2 | 1 | 20.5 | 0.0 | 8 | (some time) |
| 3 | 1 | 200.0 | 0.0 | 9 | (some time) |

I want to create a query that returns the complete row with the highest `sequence` grouped by `account, item`

The statements result for the data above should be:

| account | item | quantity | pending | sequence | update_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25.0 | 0.0 | 7 | (some time) |
| 2 | 1 | 20.5 | 0.0 | 8 | (some time) |
| 3 | 1 | 200.0 | 0.0 | 9 | (some time) |

Currently the best I know how to do is this:

```
select account, item , max(sequence) from foo group by account, item;
```

I don't know how to also select the `quantity`, `pending` and `update_time` for top row with the top sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, the best way is to use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (account, item) t.*
from t
order by account, item, sequence desc
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `window function`:

```
select * from 
( 
  select * , row_number() over (partition by account,item order by sequence desc) rn
  from foo
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the results will be grouped by quantity, pending, and update_time along with account and item (If you want to have those columns as well). Because on the basis of grouping operation only any aggregation happens. So you can directly select all the desired columns and do a group by on all these columns (that will be an easier way to do it)

`select account, item, quantity, pending, update_time, max(sequence) from foo group by account, item, quantity, pending, update_time;`

So what the above query does is, it will group records on account, item, quantity, pending and update_time and the records that it will get for a particular combination, out of them the query will fetch the maximum sequence and give the results.